# Label looks good on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, label

I recently just asked a question on here. I am asking a few more (each in a separate question so I don't get flagged). I am making a website for a client, but the label is over top of the title in Firefox but in Chrome it looks like the way I want it. View the photos below.

---

**Chrome**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

---

Here is the CSS:

```
      .label {
border: 1px solid #000;
  }
.label-danger {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
.label-danger[href]:hover,
.label-danger[href]:focus {
  background-color: #c9302c;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
        <div class="row features">
        <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
            <div class="single-fet">
                <div>
                <span class="icon-stack icon-4x">
  <i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base"></i>
  <i class="icon-ok icon-light"></i>
</span>
                </div>
<h2>Speedy Servers with <span class="label label-danger">SSDs</span>    
</h2>
<p>You will get the fastest servers possible with SSD's clocked at 1gb/s transfer.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using a CSS Reset?

Comment: I just noticed you are also missing a </div>. Make sure all tags have a respective closing tag and report back if that fixed it.

Comment: @Derek Yeah, I have a </div> under it. I just forgot to copy it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you don't want to use a CSS Reset? I bet that will fix the inconsistency

Comment: @Derek I just haven't used a CSS Reset in any of my code before. But I will try it.

Comment: As a quick test, throw this (//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css) in your html and see if it fixes it

Comment: @Derek I loaded that CSS, it worked, but then it went back to the ugly label on top of the title.

Comment: It might be a cache issue if it worked initially. Try clearing your cache and see if it fixes the issue. You can also try an incognito tab.

Comment: @Derek Still does nothing. Hm, I might just remove the label, but then it would make the other ones look off.

Comment: So... I just converted this to a JsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/e4yt3cep/1/) and checked it both on Chrome and Firefox and there seems to be no difference...

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Weird. I just tried the code from jsfiddle and it doesn't work on my local document.

Comment: So the fiddle works but the local copy does not work?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Yeah. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: It sounds like there is something going on beyond the elements you have provided us above. Try opening up the browser dev tools and inspecting the element where the issue is occurring.

Comment: This is an unsolved mystery, if anyone has any answers, add me on skype because I am going to bed. Add kolton.simpson

Answer (score -1):

```
<h2>Speedy Servers with <span class="label label-danger">SSDs</span>


h2
{
   dislay: block;
}
h2 span
{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: There is no explanation as to why this is correct, nor is there is a reason why Gecko would render display differently.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.